# Understanding asynchronous javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, redux-saga

What is the difference between following piece of codes:

Code 1:

```
export default async function syncData() {
  await Promise.all([syncData1(), syncData2()]);
}

// called in sagas.js
function* x() {
  const res = yield call(syncData);
}
```

Code 2:

```
export default function syncData() {
  return Promise.all([syncData1(), syncData2()]);
}
// called in sagas.js
function* x() {
  const res = yield call(syncData);
}
```

Comment: I believe the only difference is that the former returns an asynchronous function object, whereas the latter doesn't.

Comment: What is `call`, and why are you `yield`ing its result?

Comment: No discernible difference, both are syntax errors. You cannot have `yield` in a top level module scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between your two functions is `await` vs `return`. The missing `await` doesn't really matter, since returning a promise from an `async function` will always resolve with the promise result [similar to `return await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/1048572). So the only difference is the implicitly returned `undefined` in the first solution.

Written out explicitly:

```
export default async function syncData() {
  const res = await Promise.all([syncData1(), syncData2()]);
  return undefined;
}
```

```
export default function syncData() {
  const res = await Promise.all([syncData1(), syncData2()]);
  return res;
}
```