# Why no-return-await vs const x = await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, eslint

What is the difference between

```
return await foo()
```

and

```
const t = await foo();
return t
```

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await

Comment: You really should not do the 2nd version as it adds no benefit. The correct code line would be `return foo();`

Comment: @Igor Both code samples would be equally redundant, just written slightly different. `return foo();` would be correct though.

Comment: So why doesn't it not state `const x = await foo; return x` should be avoided?

Comment: @zehelvion - probably because detection of that is difficult to do at transpile time but both statements are equivalent and should be avoided.

Comment: Have a look at [this explanation of the `no-return-await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43353087/1048572) rule

Comment: @Igor The advantage of `return await` is that - already in V8 behind a flag - you get a full asynchronous stacktrace. That's because the full stack still is easily reconstructable as long as the original function did not yet finish. Without the `await`, if you return the promise directly, the function would be gone for good when the actual promise-creating function deeper in the call stack throws. Look for "**zero-cost async stack traces**" on https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async

Comment: FYI eslint `no-return-await` is now **deprecated**. Sonarcloud also deprecated their similar rule. There are long threads about why, the consensus seems to be that introducing this rule was a mistake.

Comment: To return an `await` is like putting a **STOP** sign at the end of the road that leads nowhere. it makes no sense. The road is the scope where the `await` resides and stop signs are to be placed in strategic places to control the code-flow within a specific scope. There is no code-flow past the `return` statement. it's all done and finished.

Comment: @vsync Please read the comments and answers here, `return await foo();` is the only correct solution.

Comment: @TamasHegedus - Please read only my comment and ignore all other comments and answers.

Answer (score 94):

Basically, because `return await` is redundant.

Look at it from a slightly higher level of how you actually use an `async` function:

```
const myFunc = async () => {
  return await doSomething();
};

await myFunc();
```

Any `async` function is already going to return a `Promise`, and must be dealt with as a `Promise` (either directly as a `Promise`, or by also `await`-ing).

If you `await` inside of the function, it's redundant because the function outside will also `await` it in some way, so there is no reason to not just send the `Promise` along and let the outer thing deal with it.

It's not syntactically wrong or incorrect and it generally won't cause issues. It's just entirely redundant which is why the linter triggers on it.

Comment: Im not sure 'send the promise along and let the outer thing deal with it' is 100% correct. In my testing, a new promise is created by both returning the promise directly, and awaiting then returning the value:
`function waitForN(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                reject(new Error('Rejected'));
            }, time);
    });
}

async function testing() {
    myPromise = waitForN(1000);
    myPromise.catch(error => console.log(error));
    return myPromise;
}`
This will result in one caught and one uncaught promise.

Comment: @TigerBear It is actually your call to `myPromise.catch()` that causes it to make a new `Promise`. Has nothing to do with `async/await`. Calling `.catch()` or `.then()` creates a new `Promise`, which is why you normally chain them and return the result of the whole thing. You should be doing `return myPromise.catch()`.

Comment: @samanime true, this creates a promise to allow chaining, but I am not returning the newly created promise, and am returning `myPromise`. You can call my above code snippet with this: `test = testing();
test.catch(e=> console.log(e))`
and now both will be caught. So I am creating a promise, but it is not the one that I am returning. This created promise is ignored and shouldn't have any affect. I am already catching the one I am returning, but when calling my function, I still need to catch the promise created and returned by the async. Does that make sense? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: If you just return the chained, it'll all be caught. You're essentially forking the chain, which creates two different paths, which is different than your second example. If you wanted to open up a question asking about that specific scenario, could probably get some pretty good answers that go more in-depth.

Comment: @samanime See my comment under OPs question. Since the introduction of "zero-cost async stack traces" in V8 `return await` is significantly different from returning the promise: You get a stack trace (in V8 at least, as of now)!

Comment: @Mörre I read through the article. Interesting stuff. Looks like it is enabled by default now. I did some testing comparing two functions: `() => p()` and `() => await p()` and calling those with `await()`. It doesn't look like there is any appreciable difference between the two. If `p = () => { throw new Error() }` you get a nice stack trace. If `p = () => Promise.reject()` you get something ugly. However, it seems like whether it is called `p()` or `await p()` gives the same result either way.

Comment: @samanime Not in my testing. I get a stack trace. Which is exactly what they claim.If you don't get what they claim you should file a report. Also beware of too simplistic tests, promises and their "microtask" queues based implementation don't behave the same if it is not truly asynchronous.

Comment: @Mörre I get stack traces too, as long as `p = () => { throw new Error() }`. However, it doesn't seem to matter if the calling function of `p` does `() => p()` or `() => await p()`.

Comment: @samanime I refer to my previous comment... whatever you are testing, it is not that functionality. It works, I tried - Google tried. Or if not than in your setup there is a bug. Find it or report it.

Comment: with `try{ return await foo() } finally { /* some code */ }` it makes sense though. Removing the `await` change the semantic to "after getting the promise, do this whatever happens" instead of the intended "after the promise settle (resolve or reject) , do this". It's quite easy to overlook such construct.

Answer (score 59):

Using `return await` does have some newly introduced benefits in v8 engine used by Node.js, Chrome and a few other browsers:

v8 introduced a `--async-stack-traces` flag which as of V8 v7.3 is enabled by default (Node.js v12.0.0).

This flags provides an improved developer experience by enriching the Error stack property with async function calls stack trace.

```
async function foo() {
  return bar();
}

async function bar() {
  await Promise.resolve();
  throw new Error('BEEP BEEP');
}

foo().catch(error => console.log(error.stack));


Error: BEEP BEEP
    at bar (<anonymous>:7:9)
```

Note that by calling `return bar();` `foo()` function call does not appear at all in the error stack. Changing it to `return await bar();` gives a much better error stack output:

```
async function foo() {
  return await bar();
}
foo();

Error: BEEP BEEP
    at bar (<anonymous>:7:9)
    at async foo (<anonymous>:2:10)
```

This indeed does provide much better error stack tracing, hence it is **HIGHLY encouraged to always await your promises.**

Additionally, async/wait now outperforms hand written promises:

> `async/await` outperforms hand-written promise code now. The key takeaway here is that we significantly reduced the overhead of async functions — not just in V8, but across all JavaScript engines, by patching the spec. [Source](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async)

Read more about these changes on the v8.dev blog: https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async#improved-developer-experience

Comment: This doesn't seem to explain why `const x = await foo()` is better than `return await foo()` if that is the case?

Comment: Well, if all you do is const x = and then return it will be able to detect it but I get the idea. It is exactly the same and the reason it doesn't warn against it, is that it doesn't want to bother with detecting the more complicated use case.

Comment: *"Inside an async function, return await is useless"* -- not if the `return` statement is inside a `try ... catch` block. In that case, awaiting will allow you to handle any errors in place.

Comment: @JohnWeisz true *with caution*. You can also add a `.catch` to avoid the extra wrapping though

Comment: "return await" is VERY useful if you run code on a current version of V8 (e.g. current node.js) - waiting before returning lets V8 compose full async. stack traces (at no "cost", because the context of the calling function is available "for free" because of the `await`).

Comment: @Mörre interesting, can you provide a source for this?

Comment: @Bamieh https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async -- scroll down to "zero-cost"; Note that the feature is enabled by default now, e.g. in current node.js and Chrome versions.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for sharing this. I'll update the answer!

Comment: Is `return await` still relevant as of 2022?

Comment: @Ginden Yes. running this in the browser's console will reveal that return await is still needed to reveal the correct stack trace

Comment: Interestingly, this is not a case in Firefox, which puts foo on stack trace in both cases.

Answer (score 25):

Because you can just

```
async function() {
  return foo();
}
```

The returned result of `async function` always is `Promise`, no matter you return the exact value or another `Promise` object inside the function body

Comment: This is the best answer here!!

Comment: instead of `return await foo()`, just `return foo()`.

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch Not any more. "return await" is VERY useful if you run code on a current version of V8 (e.g. current node.js) - waiting before returning lets V8 compose full async. stack traces (at no "cost", because the context of the calling function is available "for free" because of the `await`).

Comment: But if you later wrap the return in a try-catch, you must remember to add the await. By skipping await you are sacrificing correctness and refactorability.

Answer (score 12):

**Update:** The [`no-return-await`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-return-await) rule is [**deprecated** since `v8.46.0`](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/17417). The world is healing.

Many here are suggesting **omitting the await** and writing `return foo();`, but that **is a plain wrong advice**. There is nothing wrong with writing `return await foo();`; on the contrary, omitting `await` is a bug in your code, that I'll explain below. So turn off that `no-return-await` rule, as the ESLint and SonarCloud teams also realized in the meantime, and deprecated it.

Omitting `await` will break `try-catch` blocks, will cause `finally` blocks to run too early, and will cause some lines missing from the async stacktrace. It will also break [`explicit resource management`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-explicit-resource-management). In my opinion, skipping `await` is a misguided attempt at some abstract sense of unfounded "optimization", saving 6 characters and a microtask (EDIT: [ShortFuse just showed that it is actually not saving but adding a microtask in current v8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979225/5108418)) at the cost of code correctness. The rule of thumb is simple: if you have an async call, await it, even in return statements. Let us stick to the rule of thumb and *always* use `return await`, and switch off that `no-return-await` eslint rule.

And now the rant: I cannot stress enough how many days I spent explaining to developers who thought they had found a V8 bug when their `catch` blocks didn't run, and how many long hours I have spent arguing over pull requests that attempted to wrap the body of async functions in try blocks but without adding those missing awaits. We had multiple production incidents because of this. My developers kept pointing to the `no-return-await` rule, and when I challenged it they pointed to these answers on stack overflow with reputation in the 100K-s, saying "but the await is redundant! must not await!". I changed our ruleset, added and linked documentation, but developers tend to believe higher authority, so I had to sit down with them, running these examples together to make them believe that it's not a node bug, you just need that await. I had to do it every quarter with every new developer. It was a *professional nightmare*, convincing 70 senior developers that their basic assumptions were wrong all along. I cannot blame them, because they were relying on "reputable sources". So we need to fix it at the core of our industry, and I am grateful that ESLint changed course. Should we have pragmatically stuck to always `return await asyncFoo();` from the beginning, we wouldn't have had any of these problems today, and I could have saved hundreds of engineering hours and more of my own sanity.

Little demo, that shows missing lines from the stacktrace, and demonstrates finally blocks running too early:

```js
async function main() {
  console.log("\nStatcktrace with await shows testStackWithAwait:");
  await testStackWithAwait().catch(logStack);
  console.log("\nStatcktrace without await shows missing testStackWithoutAwait:");
  await testStackWithoutAwait().catch(logStack);
  console.log("\nFinally runs before try block ends when await is omitted:");
  await testFinallyWithoutAwait();
}

async function fnThatThrows() {
  await delay(1);
  throw new Error();
}

async function testStackWithoutAwait() {
  return fnThatThrows(); // bad
}

async function testStackWithAwait() {
  return await fnThatThrows(); // good
}

async function fnThatLogs() {
  await delay(1);
  console.log('  Running in try block');
}

async function testFinallyWithoutAwait() {
  try {
    return fnThatLogs(); // bad
  } finally {
    console.log('  Running in finally block');
  }
}

function logStack(e) {
  console.log(e.stack);
}

function delay(timeout, value) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(value);
    }, timeout);
  });
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

On Chrome 103 and 120 on Windows I get the following logs:

```
Statcktrace with await shows testStackWithAwait:
Error
    at fnThatThrows (https://stacksnippets.net/js:23:9)
    at async testStackWithAwait (https://stacksnippets.net/js:31:10)
    at async main (https://stacksnippets.net/js:14:3)

Statcktrace without await shows missing testStackWithoutAwait:
Error
    at fnThatThrows (https://stacksnippets.net/js:23:9)
    at async main (https://stacksnippets.net/js:16:3)

Finally runs before try block ends when await is omitted:
  Running in finally block
  Running in try block
```

Answer (score 3):

The significant difference between return asyncFunc and return await Promise.resolve() is by following the second approach you can catch an error if something wrong inside async function.

```
function afunction() {
  return asyncFun();
}
   
// with await
async function afunction() {
  try {
    return await asyncFun();
  } catch(err) {
    handleError(err);
    // return error result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh I think is easy to understand, we put "await" when we wait for a specific value in order to continue a process, if the process is finished (look at the return), we don't need the await syntax anymore so.

```
return await foo(); //is redundant
return foo(); //is the correct way
```