# Chaining requests inside async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm interested in chaining requests in async function.

Let's say, I need to call `request2` after `request1` inside async function.
I would do it this way:

```js
const someFunct = async () => {
  await request1();
  await request2();
  ...
}
```

But if I call `request2` inside `request1().then()` will it work? Is it the same thing?

```js
const someFunct = async () => {
  await request1()
     .then(() => request2());
  ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: seems like the same thing

Comment: Because that's the same

Comment: ok, just want to clarify
thanks

Comment: from a programming style point of view, `.then` inside a `async` function is hardly ever needed

Answer (score -4):

If you want to ensure that request2 is called after request1 inside an async function, you have a couple of options. Using await as you mentioned in your code is a common and straightforward approach, but you can also achieve this by chaining promises with **.then()**
Here's an example of both approaches:

Using await:

```
const someFunct = async () => {
  await request1();
  await request2();
  // Any code that depends on the results of request1 and request2
}
```

When you use await, the second request (request2()) will only be executed after the first request (request1()) has been completed. This means that request2() won't start until request1() has finished executing, and they will run sequentially.
Using **.then()**:

```
const someFunc = () => {
  return request1().then(() => {
    return request2();
  });
  // ...
}
```

When you use .then(), you're creating a chain of promises. In this case, request2() is only called after request1() has resolved (completed successfully). However, the difference here is that you're not using async/await, so the function someFunc is not an async function. You would handle the result of someFunc() with .then() or async/await at the calling site.

To sum it up, both approaches achieve the goal of chaining requests, but they have different syntax and behavior. If you want to use async/await and ensure that request2() doesn't start until request1() has completed, go with the first approach. If you prefer to use .then() chaining, as in the second example, you can do that too, but make sure to handle the result with .then() or await at the calling site if necessary.

Comment: [`async` functions always return promises automatically.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71953517/1426891) In both cases you will need to handle the result with `.then` or `await` at the call site.

Comment: anyone else having trouble identifying AI generated answers lately?