# Typescript async/await with Observable Or Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, async-await

Can i use the `async` with `await` like this? Am i killing the `async/await` here?
The code below is working without error, I know that the `async/await` only works with  `Promise<T>`. My `getItem` is an `Observable`. Thanks.

```
roleService.getItem({ page: p.pageIndex + 1, pageSize: p.pageSize })
.takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
.map((res: ResponseDto) => <DtoModel>res.contentBody)
.do(async (dto: DtoModel) => await this.subject.next(dto.content)) // working wihtout error
.subscribe(async (dto: DtoModel) => await (this.pager = dto.pager), //working without error
          (error: any) => Observable.throw(error));
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: You *can* do that but [you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43353087/1048572)

Comment: Why are you trying to `await` a (synchronous!) assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `async` functions the way you do but it will have no effect in your example. You have to understand that `async` function returns a promise:

```
const fn = async function() {};
fn() instanceof Promise
```

So if you use it in the observable chain you will receive a promise:

```
interval(500)
  .first()
  .map(async (v) => {
    return v;
  })
  .subscribe((v) => {
    console.log(v instanceof Promise); // logs `true`
  });
```

The way you constructed your example it won't have any effect on the observables chain because output from `do` operator is ignored and there's no listener for the output from the `subscribe` callback. So basically there's no reason to use `async` there.

If you wanted instead to wait until `async` function resolves and get the results of that function use `mergeMap` operator:

```
interval(500)
  .first()
  .map(async (v) => {
    return v;
  })
  .mergeMap((p) => {
    return p;
  })
  .subscribe((v) => {
    console.log(v);
  });
```

Comment: So how do i wait this `do((dto: DtoModel) => this.subject.next(dto.content))` before subscribe statement? I have `TODO` with that subject. I don't know how much time it takes to complete so i can't chain with `.delay(...)` Is there a better way to wait until the first statement complete before next? Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to wait for it? does it return any value?

Comment: It does not return anything. The subject send  the new value from `do(...)` where the subject is subscribed to angular component for data changes on template. So i have to wait until angular scan and complete from `changeDetecoterRef`. My component change detection strategy is in default. If i chain with `.delay(..)` then the second statement value is bound to angular but if i remove, the second value is not applied.

Comment: @Robin, sorry, I don't understand. What is unclear about my answer?

Comment: **@Maximus** I understood your answer's example above, but my problem isn't resolved. I mean how to tell the angular change detection that  `foo[]` being process while `bar[]` is updated and rendering in view? Wait till `foo[]` & `bar[]` to complete and then start rendering to the view/component etc. Like if i have `<div *ngFor="let f of foo">`  & `<div *ngIf="bar.length> 0 && getFromBar(f.id)">` so how do i chain and do synchronously? Thanks.

Comment: @Robin, this question is **completely different** than the one you posted. Update the question with every details

Comment: **Maximus** I will ask another question with details. The answer you wrote for this question is correct. Thanks.