# Can I use async await with firebase database call?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I want to use async await because I find it much more convenient than then method. But when I do I get this error:

```
const onceGetUsers = async () => await db.ref("users").once("value");
let users = await db.onceGetUsers(); // Syntax error: await is a reserved word
console.log(users);
```

Thx

Comment: You have to put it inside an `async function`. You can't just use it anywhere.

Comment: Btw, the `await` in `onceGetUsers` is [pretty useless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43353087/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not using `await` correctly.  `await` can only be used [*inside* a function declared `async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).  In your code, you're using `await` outside (unless there's more to your code that you're not showing).

Comment: You are right, async was missing in my top function.
Thx!