# Return Promise or Resolved Value from an Async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a Javascript async/await design question.

Imagine this function exists:

```
async function readFile(filename) { 
   // Asynchronously reads file and returns the content as string
}
```

Now if I were to use `readFile` with a certain parameter and return its result, I could do it either like so:

```
async function readSettings1() {
   const settings = await readFile("settings.json");
   return settings;
}
```

or:

```
async function readSettings2() {
   return readFile("settings.json");
}
```

I understand both approaches work similarly, and must be invoked identically. They both return Promises. There are a couple of syntactic differences:

1. `readSettings1` first resolves the value of `readFile` and then returns the hard result. Here, the keyword `async` is used in the function definition so I can use `await`.
2. `readSettings2` is really just a passthrough. In fact, I can omit `async` from this function definition.

My question is: are there any semantic differences between `readSettings1` and `readSettings2`? Do they behave differently in any way? Do you have a preference for either style? Why? Have you read any documentation recommending one style over the other?

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwLYAoCUMA3gL4BQZoksiKGWAHgcTAE4CmyCrWeh5ZWlDSYYYZkTaduvZiSA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0

Comment: Yes, I would recommend to omit even the `async` from `readSettings2`. Alternatively use partial application: `const readSettings = readFile.bind(null, "settings.json");`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! Your answer is great: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/417866

Comment: @Bergi Would you please care to direct me to some place where I can understand that `.bind(null, ...)` syntax/method? Is your suggestion different from `const readSettings = () => readFile("settings.json")`?

Comment: @ArashMotamedi It's basically the same. One can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).