# What would be the right approach to use await instead of Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have being using Promises for a long time, and they are always the "thing" that I use to control the workflow of my programs. Example:

```
Promise
  .resolve(obj)
  .then(doSomething1)
  .then(doSomething2)
  .catch(handleError)
```

And now, I would like to change to a try-catch style, but I don't know exactly what would be the right approach.

V1:

```
try {
  var body = await Promise
               .resolve(obj)
               .then(doSomething1)
               .then(doSomething2)
} catch (error) {
  callback(error)
}
callback(null, {
  statusCode: 200,
  body
})
```

V2:

```
try {
  var body = await Promise
               .resolve(obj)
               .then(doSomething1)
               .then(doSomething2)
               .then(body => {
                 callback(null, {
                   statusCode: 200,
                   body
                 })
               })
} catch (error) {
  callback(error)
}
```

What would be the right approach?

Comment: I don't think there is a right approach in this case. It depends on what's most maintainable.

Comment: Kind of an opinion based question, but I like V1 more. Better to have the `callback` invocations close to each other, rather than one in a `.then` and the other in the `catch` block. But my favorite snippet is actually the very first one that uses promises only.

Comment: I don't see why you would want to change to a `try` in the first place?

Comment: In any case, you would *not* invoke a callback but rather return the resolve a returned promise.

Comment: Your V1 does not work. In case of an error, the `callback` is invoked twice.

Comment: I resisted async/await until Node 8.  After using it for a few months I am glad I switched.  The big payoff is mixing async and sync code together.  You pretty much never employ Promise.resolve(...) like in your example.  It's just a lot cleaner and more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use a callback function in order to switch to `async`/`await`. An `async` function is just a Promise-returning function, and `await` is there as a convenience. So the equivalent of your original function is simply:

```
async function fn() {
  try { 
    const obj = ...;
    const result1 = await doSomething1(obj);
    const result2 = await doSomething2(result1);
    return result2;
  } catch (err) {
    return handleError(err);
  }
}
```

If you do want that callback:

```
async function fn(callback) {
  try { 
    const obj = ...;
    const result1 = await doSomething1(obj);
    const result2 = await doSomething2(result1);
    callback(null, result2);
  } catch (err) {
    callback(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: [Do not forget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/1048572) to `await` the `doSomething2()` call in your first snippet

Comment: Any return is wrapped in a `Promise.resolve`. Returning a Promise is the same as awaiting said promise and then returning the result, so it's a handy shortcut just returning the final promise.