# How to use try/catch, promise catch and async function correctly?

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch, ecmascript-2017

This is how my upload function looks like at the moment. I'm using apollo mutation in that to upload a file.

I do not understand how to use try/catch and catch of the promise (which `client.mutate()` is) correctly.
Also I declared the upload function as `async`.

So I guess I'm mixing some things up :-(

How do I catch errors correctly?

Do I need both catches? Shouldn't I replace try/catch if I'm using a async function?

```
export default async function upload (client) {
  try {
    return client.mutate({
      mutation: uploadsMutation
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert('Error', 'Could not upload files')
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await

Comment: No, you wouldn't need the `.catch()` call if you had used `await`

Comment: @Bergi Isn't `return` acting like `await`?

Comment: [Not inside a `try` block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` and `await` have to be used hand in hand - meaning nothing is automatically 'awaited' without using the `await` keyword. In your example you're just returning the Promise returned from `client.mutate`.

```
export default async function upload (client) {
  try {
    return await client.mutate({
      mutation: uploadsMutation
    });
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert('Error', 'Could not upload files')
  }
}
```

Bear in mind your `upload` function is also returning a Promise by being `async`. So calling code should handle it appropriately.

Comment: FWIW you don't have to use `await` inside an `async` function. Returning the promise directly would be fine, but of course then `try...catch` doesn't work and there wouldn't be a point in making the function `async`, but it is "ok" to do that.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I commonly make `async` functions just to denote that they return a promise, potentially being generated further down. Edited the answer the clarify that.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that I should just directly return the promise and run try/catch at the place where I call the upload function?

Comment: You _can_ if that seems appropriate to your usage. Your example dealt with handling it directly in the `upload` function. If you do that, calling code will need to `await upload(client);`.