# Using while loop in Promise()

Tags: javascript, express, promise, sequelize.js

I have a user list and i am checking all user with certain details.I am using sequelize js with express.I want to know that can we use while loop like this for searching and saving data in database.Please help me.Thanks In advance.

```
let royalty_bonus = async (sponsor) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        models.RoyaltyUser.findById(sponsor)
            .then(async (sponsorRow) => {
                let user_level = 1;
                let sponsor_id = sponsorRow;

                try {
                    while (sponsor_id != null && user_level <= 3) {
                        let level_length = await getLevel(sponsor_id.id, user_level);
                        if (user_level === 1 && level_length.length === 3) {
                            console.log('Level One Achieved By ', sponsor_id.id);
                        } else if (user_level === 2 && level_length.length === 9) {
                            console.log('Level Two Is Achieved By ', sponsor_id.id);
                        } else {
                            console.log('No Level');
                        }

                        await models.RoyaltyUser.findOne({where: {id: sponsor_id.sId}})
                            .then((sponsor_new_row) => {
                                sponsor_id = sponsor_new_row;
                            })
                            .catch((e) => {
                                console.log(' Inner Catch Error ', e.message);
                                reject();
                            });
                        user_level++;
                    }
                    resolve();
                }
                catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }

            })
            .catch((e) => {
                reject('catch ', e.message);
            });
    });

};
router.get('/royalty_user', async (req, res, next) => {
    royalty_bonus(4)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('done');
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log('Catch two', e.message);
        })
});
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! And avoid using `then` when you have `async`/`await`!

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: this is working as expected.But i am not sure that this will not fail at certain point.i am new to express.I just want to know that this kind of promise execution is right or wrong.

Comment: The `while` loop you asked about in the question title is fine, the rest is awful :-)

Comment: can u tell me how can i remove awful things?? bcz this is out of my scope

Comment: Thanks a lot bergi.U are awesome.

Comment: @Bergi i required one more Help.please can u sort this out.

Comment: Where? With what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), avoid [`return await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43353087/1048572), and don't mix `.then` callbacks with `async`/`await` syntax. You can simplify a lot:

```
async function royalty_bonus(sponsor) {
    const sponsorRow = await models.RoyaltyUser.findById(sponsor);
    let user_level = 1;
    let sponsor_id = sponsorRow;

    while (sponsor_id != null && user_level <= 3) {
        let level_length = await getLevel(sponsor_id.id, user_level);
        if (user_level === 1 && level_length.length === 3) {
            console.log('Level One Achieved By ', sponsor_id.id);
        } else if (user_level === 2 && level_length.length === 9) {
            console.log('Level Two Is Achieved By ', sponsor_id.id);
        } else {
            console.log('No Level');
        }

        const sponsor_new_row = await models.RoyaltyUser.findOne({where: {id: sponsor_id.sId}});
        sponsor_id = sponsor_new_row;
        user_level++;
    }    
}

router.get('/royalty_user', (req, res, next) => {
    royalty_bonus(4).then(() => {
        console.log('done');
    }, e => {
        console.log('Catch two', e.message);
    });
});
```