# How to return value from promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have a promise that returns a promise.

For the moment my code is :

```
async isRepo() {
  return await this.gitPromise.checkIsRepo();
}
```

[image]

But I need to return the value of the promise (true or false) to use the function isRepo() at other places.

Even with "then", I didn't success to return the value of the promise and not the promise itself.

I will need it to do for instance :

```
if (await isRepo()) {
  // true : todo
} else {
  // false : something else
}
```

Comment: No, you can't return the value - it doesn't exist yet when you are calling the function. You can only return the promise - which you already do - and then `await` it in your `if` condition - which you already do and which should work.

Comment: The await will not work in the if statement unless that if statement is within an async function.

Comment: Btw, [drop the pointless `return await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/1048572). Just `isRepo() {
  return this.gitPromise.checkIsRepo();
}`

Comment: Why did you [add the `await` in an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54389363/revisions)? Do you have a problem at all? What's the error, what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
isRepo() {
    return gitPromise().checkIsRepo();
  }
```

And in an other function :

```
async myFunction() {
   if (await isRepo()) {
     // do my stuffs
   else {
     // something else
   } 
}
```