# waiting for fetch results in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I'm calling fetch a lot so I'm trying to make it a reusable function.

```
async function getXML(url) {
    const result = await fetch(url);
    const xml = await result.text().then(( str ) => {
        return new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'application/xml');
    });
    log(xml); //logs fine
}
```

I call it from `var xml = getXML(url).then( work_with_setup_xml(xml) );`

The function 'work_with_setup_xml' starts without data.
How far off course am I?

Comment: well you do not return from getXML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fixing the `return` statement in `getXML` (as suggested in the other comments), your call is wrong. It should be either

```
getXML(url).then(work_with_setup_xml);
```

or

```
getXML(url).then(function(xml) { work_with_setup_xml(xml) });
```

or

```
var xml = await getXML(url);
work_with_setup_xml(xml);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
async function getXML(url) {
  const result = await fetch(url);
  const str = await result.text();
  return new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'application/xml');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So how about returning the data for a change?

```
async function getXML(url) {
    const result = await fetch(url);

    return await result.text().then(( str ) => {
        return new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'application/xml');
    });
}
```

And actually using it:

```
let xml = getXML(url).then(xml => work_with_setup_xml(xml));
```

Comment: [Avoid `return await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43353087/1048572), or even in general [mixing `await` with `.then(…)` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572).