# does async/await nesting have performance consequences?

Tags: javascript, async-await

lets consider we have N async functions like:

```
async function1(){
  return await fetch(...);
}
.
.
.
async functionN(){
  return await fetch(...);
}
```

then we have a function like:

```
async wrapper(){
   let var = await fetch(...);
   function1();
   .
   .
   .
   functionN();
}
```

would this create one big microtask queue that would effectively block ui thread going to next task before all called functions resolved their `awaits`?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "nesting" here. Is it on purpose that you are not `await`ing the `functionN()` calls?

Comment: There is only one microtask queue, and it exists in the runtime, outside of your code. It does not get "created".

Comment: yes, its on purpose. a kind of fire and forget...but i am actually questioning is it a real forget or remembering it on a huge microtask queue and blocked ui?

Comment: [Measure it](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: @Bergi i am aware its only one microtask queue outside of my code:). correct phrasing would be: would the code above create a lot of microtasks in microtask queue scheduled for execution before new task?

Comment: Nothing is scheduled on the queue until any of the promises are settled.

Comment: Btw, [don't use `return await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43353087/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the microtask queue until promises *resolve*. Until then other tasks and (UI) events can be processed.

This is because the `await` operator will make the corresponding `async` function return immediately, allowing other JS code to execute. In your case the promise is returned by `fetch`, which in practice will not resolve *immediately*. So there is nothing blocking here.

Then when the HTTP response makes the `fetch` promise resolve, a microtask will indeed be created, which, when when executed will *restore* the corresponding `async` function's execution context. Your example function has nothing else to do, so that is quickly done.

Note that it does not matter whether this function was originally called from within some other function: at this stage, only that particular function's execution context (in which an awaited promise resolved) is restored without any pre-existing callstack. So it does not return *again* to the wrapping function. That already happened in the first phase and will not happen again.

Then again there is free event processing until the next `fetch` promise resolves. And so it continues.

Comment: thanks for your details answer. that last part was particularily helpful!