# call method with two definitions with spread syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to call a `super` method where the definitions are the same as this method.

I call it like this:

```
return await super.chunk(...args)
```

However, it gives me this error:

> Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 0 or more.

So, I tried to type the value passed in like this:

```
return await super.chunk(...args as [number, number | Function, Function?])
```

But that gives me this error:

> Argument of type 'number | Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
>
> Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Here is the full block:

```
  public async chunk(max: number, offset: number, callback: (results: any[]) => void): Promise<DB>
  public async chunk(max: number, callback: (results: any[]) => void): Promise<DB>
  public async chunk(...args: (number | Function)[]): Promise<DB> {
    this.table(this.$table)
    return await super.chunk(...args as [number, number | Function, Function?])
  }
```

Is there anyway that I can call the `super method` without having to call it different times within if statements with different arguments?

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20async%20chunk(max%3A%20number%2C%20offset%3A%20number%2C%20callback%3A%20(results%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%0D%0A%20%20public%20async%20chunk(max%3A%20number%2C%20callback%3A%20(results%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%0D%0A%20%20public%20async%20chunk(...args%3A%20(number%20%7C%20Function)%5B%5D)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20stuff%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20async%20chunk(max%3A%20number%2C%20offset%3A%20number%2C%20callback%3A%20(results%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%0D%0A%20%20public%20async%20chunk(max%3A%20number%2C%20callback%3A%20(results%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%0D%0A%20%20public%20async%20chunk(...args%3A%20(number%20%7C%20Function)%5B%5D)%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20await%20super.chunk(...args%20as%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%20%7C%20Function%2C%20Function%3F%5D)%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20child%20%3D%20new%20Child()%3B%0D%0Achild.chunk(1%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D)%3B)

Comment: What are the parameters of `this.chunk()` ? Is it also `...args`?

Comment: `this.chunk()` and `super.chunk()` are the exact same definitions and parameters, just different bodies

Comment: I coded this problem in TypeScript playground and it worked for me (press run): https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20myFunction(...args)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%20extends%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20myFunction(...args)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20super.myFunction(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20child%20%3D%20new%20Child()%3B%0D%0Achild.myFunction(1%2C%202%2C%203)%3B

Comment: You are missing all the overload definitions

Comment: `super.chunk(...args as [any, any, any])` works, but that's pretty nasty.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in TypeScript's playground? I'm not understanding.

Comment: @AskYous Yes I can however the link is too long to share.

Comment: Yeah I almost had that problem. Share the code using pastebin.com or something and I can put it into TS playground.

Comment: @AskYous I added the link to the question

Comment: Thanks. I played around and noticed that typescript thinks there's only 2 functions in `super` for some reason. Not sure why: https://i.imgur.com/pBw1fSs.png

Comment: Btw, [avoid `return await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/1048572)! You might not even need an `async` method if you don't expect `this.table` to throw.

Comment: There was a syntax errors in the TS playground link you shared. One of the super functions is missing its implementation.

Comment: @AskYous That's how overloads are supposed to work. The implementation (the `...args` on in this case) is not exposed as a callable function. This is basically the problem OP is describing. It's hard to generically call overloaded functions.

Comment: Ok. Not sure I can help as I don't know about overloads in TS.

Comment: This works `[number, number, ((results: any[]) => void)]` however, it isn't correct.

Comment: I guess the type should be `[number, number, Function] | [number, Function]` (or with the full type spelled out instead of `Function`)

Comment: I just tried that too. That also errors out for me.