# Why is Sonarqube telling me await is redundant in async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have an error in SonarQueb that says

`Refactor this redundant 'await' on a non-promise.`

Below is my JS code. Is the await really redundant? What would be the 'correct' non-redundant code (that keeps the same functionality)? Just remove `await`?

```
async getNavLink(name: string) {
    console.log(`getNavLink ${name}`);
    return await element(by.cssContainingText('.navigation li span', name));
}
```

Comment: that depends on what the code called post `await` does, i guess its internally Async implemented

Comment: if the `element` function doesn't return a promise, then `await` makes no actual difference and removing it will be inconsequential.

Comment: TL;DR: Sonar was wrong, the rule has been removed from the default ruleset. Always use `return await asyncFn(...)`, never skip await.

Answer (score 3):

In short: Sonar was wrong, you never skip that await in `return await asyncFn();`.

There used to be a performance benefit argument, there also used to be people saying it is the same anyway so why don't we spare those 6 keystrokes?

But towards the end of 2022 the industry is slowly arriving at an understanding that this rule was a bad idea.

The performance claims were shown to be false:
[Are there performance concerns with `return await`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353087/are-there-performance-concerns-with-return-await/70979225#70979225)

And also it turns out it is not the same. By skipping `await` an enclosing try-catch will not catch the errors and an enclosing `try-finally` will not wait for the promise, so the `finally` block will run sooner than expected. The [new `using` keyword for "Explicit Resource Management"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-2.html) will also be broken if you don't await in return.

It is planned to remove the rule from the default ruleset:
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/await-should-not-be-used-redundantly/29074/8