# Async/await inside of Promise then

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have a `400` returning a body with errors I need to get at. However, since `fetch` doesn't actually fail that status code, I handle it in the `then` and return a rejected `Promise`. But, because `then` generally returns a `Promise`, I can't issue a `reject` without awaiting the response from `json()`.

```
dispatch({
  type: 'LOGIN',
  payload: fetch(`${host}/api/signin/`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  }).then(async res => {
    if (res.status >= 400) {
      return Promise.reject(await res.json());
    }

    return await res.json();
  })
});
```

Is there a better way to handle this? It's technically working, but I feel like I'm probably handling it wrong by making `then` synchronous.

Comment: Personally, I like the way you did it.

Comment: The normal process is to use two .then's, but i see no real problem with combining them using async/await.

Comment: I've created a function in my library that wraps fetch with an async function of my own and I await fetch itself within that function to avoid `then` completely.

Comment: Why do you want to reject >400 in the first place?

Comment: I would recommend to [avoid mixing `await` with `.then(…)` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572), and to [avoid `return await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/1048572). Also consider using [`response.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) instead of that `.status` check.

Answer (score -1):

I feel like I am missing something here, but couldn't you just console log the rejection?

```
somepromise.then(
  res => { ... },
  err => { console.log(err)}
)
```

Comment: aren't you missing a `,` before `err`

Comment: `fetch` won't `reject` on `400`

Comment: Thanks @AbishekAditya