# Rewrite error catching higher order function to catch async errors?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await, functional-programming

Here I have a function that works well for catching sync errors, and doing something with them before re-throwing them.

```
    function logExceptions<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(func: T): (...funcArgs: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> {
      return (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
        try {
          return func(...args);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(func.name + " caused an error")
          throw err;
        }
      };
    }

function syncExample() { 
  throw new Error()
}

logExceptions(syncExample)();
```

console.log

> "syncExample caused an error"

Can I rewrite this function to become async agnostic and also work for async functions?

```
async function asyncExample() { 
  throw new Error()
}
logExceptions(asyncExample)();
```

desired console.log

> "asyncExample caused an error"

actual console.log

> ""

Comment: "*Can I rewrite this function to become async agnostic and also work for async functions?*" - no. You should write a separate function for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I rewrite this function to become async agnostic and also work for async functions?

No. While you could try to overload it and detect whether the function would return a promise or not, that's very fragile. Better write a separate function for wrapping asynchronous functions:

```
function logExceptions<T extends any[], U>(func: (...args: T) => PromiseLike<U>): (...args: T) => Promise<U> {
  return async (...args) => {
    try {
      return await func(...args);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(func.name + " caused an error")
      throw err;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT [No](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Bergi about the new function.

---

Typescript doesn't like it when we return directly the `ReturnType` in case of `async` method use. I guess it's because I havent specified that `ReturnType` must be of type `Promise`, but I've found now way how to specify it.

> type ReturnType any> = T extends (...args:
>   any) => infer R ? R : any Obtain the return type of a function type
>
> The return type of an async function or method must be the global
>   Promise type.(1064)

I've found a turnaround by extracting what's templated inside of the `Promise` and redeclaring it.

```
type ExtractPromiseTemplate<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? U : T

function logExceptions<T extends (...args: any[]) => ReturnType<T>>(func: T): (...funcArgs: Parameters<T>) => Promise<ExtractPromiseTemplate<ReturnType<T>>> {
      return async (...args: Parameters<T>): Promise<ExtractPromiseTemplate<ReturnType<T>>> => {
        try {
          console.log('Will call now');
          const ret = await func(...args);

          return ret as ExtractPromiseTemplate<ReturnType<T>>;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(func.name + " caused an error");

          throw err;
        }
      };
    }

async function asyncExample() { 
  throw new Error('Example')
}

logExceptions(asyncExample)();
```

---

Call the following code to test the validity of the returned value :

```
type ExtractPromiseTemplate<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? U : T

function logExceptions<T extends (...args: any[]) => ReturnType<T>>(func: T): (...funcArgs: Parameters<T>) => Promise<ExtractPromiseTemplate<ReturnType<T>>> {
      return async (...args: Parameters<T>): Promise<ExtractPromiseTemplate<ReturnType<T>>> => {
        try {
          console.log('Will call now');
          const ret = await func(...args);

          return ret as Promise<ExtractPromiseTemplate<ReturnType<T>>>;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(func.name + " caused an error");

          throw err;
        }
      };
    }

async function asyncExample():Promise<string> { 
  return 'a';
}

(async() => {
  const ret = await logExceptions(asyncExample)();
})();
```

---

---

[New playground for @bergi comment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=24&ssc=6&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbAAqIPYFsCWAzhACoS5gA2ywEAPCQHxQC8UJUECEAdgCaEoWPEQgAZfAGt6+HgDMIiKAFVmAfhVQAXOwBQuuQFce6fNh5RK2AObxUEMMDM9CDTt36CAFADo-yRGtCHWQeEABtAF0ASlZmYQJiOlCQRkYvIxMdEmidXz9M1ABBQOChAORcCFpEVyZYlnicRPoU5gBvXShunsRqw0QLZEIQEyh8nwCgnQwKqpq6xlyhZtFksOZGqE6e3agkEG2uvd3Uc0JsSggfK2svAHIAdXxKSihUZFeoHmwAd3vogBuY4nbpnFzAKB9SFsZC-ZD4SGFCZTQhA-Sg3r9QZQ6rAzEAX3eNFQAAtxopELEdpj3udLtdbhljKgfDxKtAANRQABExMMxD4UFCnEQOEQPPRINBwFJOF+osQ+NBBOl3QJyvV+mGo1QUEKTnMwpGJnglSoEC8uQSa0ISFk1g6UGO0IGFnuyHuwNVui8OpMVriRzB50h0NYwvhiMsNjsDkNLj9JtQZooV2iVu9GaBQA)

Comment: That looks pretty great. Would it be possible to simplify the solution and maybe avoid the ExtractPromiseTemplate if the function was rewritten to only handle async functions?

Comment: This method already only reference async functions. The thing is, typescript is making an error when simply returning `ReturnType<T>` that's why I used a workaround. If someone reading my answer could find an other way it would be great. I agree it is pretty big.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I think it should be `logExceptions<T extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>>` to make sure the passed-in function is asynchronous. You then could probably drop the `Promise<ExtractPromiseTemplate<…>>` and just use `ReturnType<T>` for the return types.

Comment: Also you shouldn't need to cast the `ret` to a different type, it should just work - and notice that `ret` is not a promise.

Comment: @Bergi I've created a playground using `Promise<any>`, the thing is, we lose the type of the returned parameter. `ret` will be of type `any`. Also you are right, I made a mistake on the returned value type that I'll edit right now.

Comment: Ah, I see. What I would've suggested causes "*Type `(...args: any[]) => Promise<any>` is not assignable to type `T`.
  `(...args: any[]) => Promise<any>` is assignable to the constraint of type `T`, but `T` could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint `(...args: any[]) => Promise<any>`.*"

Comment: [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGzgcwKIA8IFMAOsCAzgDwAqiuWUuYAJsYgBQB07AhgE5rEBciDmACeAbQC6ASkQBeAHyIAClzgBbGMVykhwuXOahIA8pOOIA3gChEN211xQQXJMw7FhkFu1bde0+RbWtsFQXMKBwZGIECRwyLisqGjMAOQA6jDIyNEcWYhgcADuKZIA3EFRNjFgxFCI9nUygoUcMHWGEGycPMRllhWVDU5IDeWViAC+OVAQABYsuFxc0lbjVbHxiegG4BCsYByquIgA1IgARDkgmvSCSIsqXOd9A1FQsyqFVEtjlROvk2kbkQ5F+Nn+ljcHggiA6RCQUMg2EO+HizFMyjUGi0tS4MDAaAU5kQQSGzkQKQ4KXKENc7kg6NkRKC1Vq9QcsmarTqSWweEI8BqdOhyNUqNwknRNMlZSAA) works but is ugly (and slightly incorrect) as it requires a cast.

Comment: @Bergi you should post it as an answer. It's a valid alternative. Hope someone would find a better way thought

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT Posted an answer now that does it properly by just using two type parameters

Answer (score 0):

This can leverage `Awaited`

```
function logExceptions<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  func: T
): (...funcArgs: Parameters<T>) => Promise<Awaited<ReturnType<T>>> {
  return async (...args: Parameters<T>) => {
    try {
      return await func(...args);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(func.name + " caused an error");
      throw err;
    }
  };
}
```