# Return Promise<Class> from async method

Tags: typescript, fetch-api

I'm learning typescript and messing around with an API endpoint, I've created a method which takes a value, makes a request to an external API and gets the data, populates the model PortalDetail and returns it back to the front end.

However, the returned data is always null.  I have checked the `portalUrl` and the value exists, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

Here is the code in question:

```
const CheckUri = async (organisationCode: string): Promise<PortalDetail | null> => {

    await fetch(`${uris.appCode}${organisationCode}`)
        .then(async (data) => {
            const portalUrl = await data
                .text()
                .then((html) => html)
                .catch(() => null)

            console.log(portalUrl); // This has a value
            console.log(data); // So does this

            if (data?.status === 200 && portalUrl) {

                console.log("inside if"); // This also gets printed

                return new PortalDetail(portalUrl, organisationCode);
            }
        })
        .catch(() => {

        })
        .finally(() => {

        })

    return null;

}
```

Here is the code calling the method:

```
const CheckOrgnisationCode = async (orgCode: string) => {

    if (!orgCode || orgCode.includes(' ')) {
      return;
    }

    console.log("before checkuri method")

    var portalDetails = await CheckUri(orgCode);

    console.log("finiahes ");
    

    console.log(portalDetails);

    if (portalDetails?.portalUrl) {
      await StoreData(saved.portalURL, portalDetails?.portalUrl);
      await StoreData(saved.portalCode, orgCode);
    }

  }
```

Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused with `async/await` and `Promises`.

1. Never call `await` & `.then` simultaneously on a `Promise`
2. Use `try/catch` inside `async` functions when you want to handle errors.

```
const CheckUri = async (organisationCode: string): Promise<PortalDetail | null> => {
  try {
    const resp = await fetch(`${uris.appCode}${organisationCode}`)
    if (!resp.ok) { // almost same as resp.status !== 200
      throw resp
      // or

      // const text = await resp.text()
      // throw text
    }
    const portalUrl = await resp.text()

    return new PortalDetail(portalUrl, organisationCode)
  } catch (err) {
    // console.error(err)
    return null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are always returning null, no matter the result of the fetch call - see the last line of the function:

```
return null
```

You have two options:

1. Return the `fetch` call directly:

```
return fetch(...);
```

2. Store the `fetch` call return value in a variable and return that variable:

```
const response = await fetch(...);
return response;
```

Both options are equivalent.

And since you are using an async function, you can use try/catch like in sync code like in the following really simplified example:

```
try {
  const response = await fetch('url');
  const html = await response.text();

  // note: fetch doesn't throw for status codes >= 400
  if (response?.status === 200) {
    return html;
  } else {
    throw Error('Server error');
  }
} catch (error) {
  return null
}
```

Comment: …and [don't ignore errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251622/should-i-avoid-try-catch-in-every-single-async-await-on-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing promise.then with async/await. And it usually it gets to such results. Choose one - async/await is more readable.

The issue is in the first `.then` you return something. You await the call but you do not assign it to anything

```js
.then(async (data) {
  if (data?.status === 200 && portalUrl) {
    //this return will not return the result to the CheckUri  
    return new PortalDetail(portalUrl, organisationCode);
  }
});
```

Here is what you should to to your code

```js
const CheckUri = async (organisationCode: string): Promise<PortalDetail | null> => {

    const RESLUT = await fetch(`${uris.appCode}${organisationCode}`) 
        //...

    return RESULT;
```

Here is your code with async.await which I believe is more readable.

```js
const CheckUri = async (organisationCode: string): Promise<PortalDetail | null> => {

    try {
        const fetchResult = await fetch(`${uris.appCode}${organisationCode}`);
        const portalUrl = await fetchResult.text();

        if (fetchResult.status === 200 && portalUrl) {
          return new PortalDetail(portalUrl, organisationCode);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }

    } catch(e) {
       //handle the error
       console.error("We couldn't check the URI", e);
       return null
    } finally {
        //do the cleanup logic
    }
}
```

[Typescript playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTDOBcFcCNoUwCYAIDGAbAhqUAodXQkAFAewCdwM0AROSgSzQG8clUSA7CMyFccgBQAHGGnookZOBgSc0ATyRDylNAFUyaAFxJu9DgHMANEtHjJ02RwVJyBjB3qgM4epwDCJBHB17DASiQmAF8cUJwQCBh4ZEgyJyQANwx4jGg0ODxOCCQ4hIBeIKQMISFPbyQdACIqpGCAbhwI4HAACzgLKnZvLK5wJHd2lABrDXokQqx5DgkBOwcnFzcOcp9dcHiAnSIyEgBbJzgAHlIKKloGNCQAHyQOSDQ0AD4Jl5ZWNiQNxRZPv-Y%20kgAGZ0FCtABKcFAD36kwA7hh6P0QeAwQIAAYAEiYeVAADoSmUvHBgtj5o5nK4PMTguj-I1-p8UNl%20sozupNBNigikcDQRCoTC8eA4AAPcACelNRlsehApACFFgyHQtDgPEQFyQQj5XVIABMAAZDUgAGSmpQqKgaNCBX4ythSKBkDh3OBw4hWmh0RFoYRem0mcmLKkrYlSh2hB1wNCgDr2h2OuhxV33R4MmXhP7BVAuNFwO0ff4gVoOBAZL7tJBwMi7MhFv7MrgkDJ4mt1gRVADqHWZDwQHAA5P0wXBhhI2h01OCAJJVEwFjP-J0pu4PNANnNA-RUGwJ4vAWSV3sZByQIRINAkAziTdhIA)

Comment: typo on `RESULT`