# Using a try and catch to await an axios request so I can use the response in another function it´s good practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I´m practising React making a web site but I want to consume some APIs. The problem is that I had a problem when making an Axios request since it´s asynchronous, and when I tried calling it in a function the function ended before receiving the response from Axios showing me empty and undefined values. So searching on the iIternet I found a piece of code that worked like a charm, but I don't know if it's a good practice or how/why it works.

Here´s the code I´m currently using:

```
export async function ttest1 (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    {
        return await axios.get('url');
    } try {
        const response = await ttest1(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
}
```

Can somebody tell me how/why it works and if it's a good practice or there are better ways to make a function wait for an axios request to end so it can use the response data.

Comment: Please check your parenthesis (nesting and indentation), I cannot make sense of your code, and therefore not answer your question

Comment: However this sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251622/should-i-avoid-try-catch-in-every-single-async-await-on-node-js and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896442/why-is-catcherr-console-errorerr-discouraged - can you confirm that these answer your question?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, the last closing brace was an error, about the other comment, actually it helped me a lot. Thanks!!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the braces