# Node.js Performance: Detecting Memory Leaks and High CPU Usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have written a Node.js API that reads data from collections. Collection containing 1000 records. Each record contains 300 sub-payload data points.

```
const data = await csvModel['csvFiles'].find({ "created_datetime": today_datetime });
if (data.length > 0) {
    for (let mappData of data) {
        await payloadMapping(mappData.payload);
    }
}
```

Inside payloadMapping we are doing mapping of field and stored inside new collection

```
const payloadMapping = async (jsonPayload) => {
  try {
      let categoryId = await getCategoryID(jsonPayload["category"][0].parent_category);
      let totalEvent = jsonPayload["category"][0].event.length;
      if (categoryId) {
          let allExistingEvent = await getAllEvents(categoryId);
          let eventInsertData = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < totalEvent; i++) {
              let duplicate_event = false;
              let eventPayload = {};
              eventPayload["categoryId"] = categoryId;
              eventPayload["start"] = jsonPayload["category"][0].event[i].start;
              /*Check no two event at same times */
              if (allExistingEvent.length > 0) {
                  allExistingEvent.forEach(item => {
                      let result = item.categoryId.every((element, index) => element === categoryId[index]);
                      if (result && item.start === eventPayload.start) {
                          duplicate_event = true;
                      }
                  });
              }
              /*Check ends */
              if (!duplicate_event) {
                  eventPayload["title"] = jsonPayload["category"][0].event[i].title;
                  eventPayload["description"] = jsonPayload["category"][0].event[i].description;
                  eventPayload["event_location"] = jsonPayload["category"][0].event[i].location;
                  eventPayload["duration"] = jsonPayload["category"][0].event[i].duration;
                  eventPayload["status"] = 1;
                  eventInsertData.push(eventPayload);
              }
          }
          if (eventInsertData.length > 0) {
            try {
                await Events.insertMany(eventInsertData);
            } catch (mongoErr) {
              console.log(mongoErr);
            }
          }
      } else {
        console.log("Category collection not exist" + jsonPayload["category"][0].name);
      }
    } catch (error) {
    console.log(error, "catch error")
  }
}
```

This function list all events based on parent_category

```
const getCategoryID = (parent_category) => {
  return new Promise( (resolve) => {
    (async () => {
      const query = { parent_category: parent_category};
      let categoryArray = [];
      let categoryResult = await categoryModel.find(query);
      if (categoryResult.length > 0) {
        categoryResult.forEach((item) => {
          categoryArray.push(item._id.toString());
        })
      }
      resolve(categoryArray);
    });
  });
};
```

This function list all events based on category_id

```
const getAllEvents = (categoryId) => {
  return new Promise( (resolve) => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const eventLists = await Events.find({ 'categoryId': categoryId }, { "categoryId": 1, "start": 1 });
        if (eventLists.length > 0) {
          resolve(eventLists);
        } else {
          resolve([]);
        }
      } catch (dbErr) {
        console.log("dbErr", dbErr);
        resolve([]);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

I have given following configuration to POD

Resource Limits

resoureces:
**requests:**

memeory: "250Mi",
cpu: "50m",

**limits:**
memeory: "8000Mi"
cpu: "4000m"

While running the API I am getting high memory and CPU utilization. Please help me to optimize the code.

Comment: `(async () => { … });` doesn't do anything. And [should never be used in the executor of a `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572) anyway!

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251622/should-i-avoid-try-catch-in-every-single-async-await-on-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations:

- Each call to `getCategoryID` and `getAllEvents` potentially generates a
  new database query. Minimize the number of queries by batching
  operations or restructuring how data is retrieved and processed.
- Ensure your MongoDB collections have appropriate indexes on fields
  that are frequently queried (parent_category, categoryId, etc.). This
  can dramatically reduce the time taken for each query, thus reducing
  CPU usage.
- If possible, paginate your database queries to avoid loading all
  records into memory at once. This can help manage memory usage more
  effectively.
- Your use of `new Promise` with an immediately-invoked async function
  inside `getCategoryID` and `getAllEvents` is unnecessary since async
  functions already return a promise. Simplify these functions to
  directly return the result of the query.
- Tools like Node.js built-in profiler (node --inspect), Chrome
  Developer Tools, or dedicated NPM packages like memwatch-next and
  heapdump can help identify memory leaks.
- Ensure that CPU-intensive tasks are handled asynchronously to prevent
  blocking the event loop. Consider using worker threads for heavy
  computation tasks.

Here’s how you can refactor getCategoryID for simplification:

```
const getCategoryID = async (parent_category) => {
  try {
    const query = { parent_category: parent_category };
    const categoryResult = await categoryModel.find(query);
    return categoryResult.map(item => item._id.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching category ID:", error);
    return [];
  }
};
```