# complexity is x it is time to do something..., visual studio code

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using vscode for a react native app. And I am wondering if the message:

> complexity is x it is time to do something...

is always useful.

Because for example I have this function:

```
import { API_URL } from "@env";
import { retrieveToken } from "../authentication/token";
export const fetchCategoryData = async () => {
    const token = await retrieveToken();
    try {
        if (token) {
            const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/categories/main_groups/`, {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            });
            return await response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(token);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        Error("can't retreive data");
    }
}
```

And vscode says:

> complexity is 6 it is time to do something...

retrieveToken:

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export const retrieveToken = async () => {
    try {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Token");

        return token;
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Question: How to improve the function where the message says: complexity is 6 it is time to do something...?

Comment: You are probably using a linter of some sort. The message just means that your function might be overly complex and it might be better to refactor said function. This question is perhaps more suitable for [codereview.se] ([read the guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777)).

Comment: But the big question is: is it possible to refactor this? Or can I ignore the message?

Comment: `throw new Error(token);` seems quite pointless, `token` would be `null`. Why not just let the original exception from `AsyncStorage.getItem` propagate?

Comment: Also -> `Error("can't retreive data");`  Does nothing useful.

Comment: `Error("can't retreive data");` probably doesn't do what you want. Did you mean to `throw` a `new Error`?

Comment: @Bergi. Oke, because it is a try...catch...I mean how to do it then different?

Comment: @Bergi. Oke, I can omit the else {
            throw new Error(token);
        }

Comment: When using `try / catch`, really consider if it's required.  In 99% of cases exceptions should be allowed to propagate.   Classic errors you see on SO are people doing `try {} catch (e) { console.error(e); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the big question is: is it possible to refactor this?

[Don't use `try`/`catch` everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251622/should-i-avoid-try-catch-in-every-single-async-await-on-node-js). Use it only where you can actually *handle* the error. Which in your example appears to be nowhere - any error needs to be handled by the caller of `fetchCategoryData`.

So you can simplify the whole thing to

```
export const retrieveToken = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("Token");
    if (!token) throw new Error('Got empty token from storage');
    return token;
}

export const fetchCategoryData = async () => {
    const token = await retrieveToken();
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/categories/main_groups/`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    });
    return await response.json();
}
```

which have a cyclomatic complexity of 2 and 1 respectively.

Comment: After `token = ..` the OP could also just do -> `if (!token) throw new Error('No Token')`,  just saves doing a fetch that would be invalid.

Comment: @Keith I understood that `retrieveToken` would already throw an exception (not catch it to `return null`) if it cannot get a token. Are you saying that `getItem` might legitimately fulfill with `null` or some other falsy value?

Comment: Yes, from what I can gather @react-native-async-storage/async-storage works like localeStorage returning `null`,  but of course you can also throw inside `retrieveToken` like you have just updated with.   Either way is good. :)