# Where sholud I further precess on after reading file with a try-catch block in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When reading a file with Node.js promise API, I need to use try-catch block. While I can't decide where should I place the further processing code, directly inside try block or outside the try-catch block. Here is one example:

```js
import { readFile } from 'node:fs/promises';

try {
  const JSONString = await readFile("./config.json", "utf-8");
  // further processing directly inside try block
  const object = JSONString === ""? {}: JSON.parse(JSONString);
  ...
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

```js
import { readFile } from 'node:fs/promises';

let JSONString = "";
try {
  JSONString = await readFile("./config.json", "utf-8");
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
// further processing outside try-catch block
const object = JSONString === ""? {}: JSON.parse(JSONString);
...
```

Comment: The general rule around try/catch is "can you keep going despite the error". If you can, second pattern. If you can't, first one (and then have a return in that catch, because that codepath should now be dead. However, remember that _both_ readFile and JSON.parse can throw, so a single try/catch won't be enough.

Comment: Well should your catch block handle errors from `JSON.parse` or not? We can't tell you.

Comment: To expand on @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, "*if you can't keep going despite the error*", then maybe [you shouldn't use `try`/`catch` in that place at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2737328/1048572) (also true [for promises](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50896442/1048572) and [for async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63251622/1048572)). Or at least you should re-`throw` an error from the `catch` block. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44663864/1048572) on error handling patterns for `async`/`await`.