# Why Async function in Next JS returns empty object in my Typescript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, next.js

I'm having some problems with async function.

I have a class in my ../lib folder for processing data from an API website but i ran into problems when i try to load the api data in async function.

The async function dont even return anything, not even when i create object and try to return it inside the async function

All i get is {} empty object every time i call the function

Here is my code:

```
 private procurr(obj){
    // Here we start processing
    const mainObj = async function(ob) {
        var robj : any = [];
        var item = {};
        var i : number = 0;
        var total : number = 10;
        try{
            for(item in ob){
                let res2 = await axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/'+item+'.json');
                const obji = await res2.data;
                var word : string = this.help.mode(this.help.words(obji.title));
                if(word.length > 0){
                    if(i < total){
                        robj[i] = (this.help.inArr(word, robj)) ? this.help.incScore(robj[i]) : {'word': word, 'score':1};
                        // increment
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error);
        }
        
        // return JSON.parse(robj);
        return ob;       
    }

    // exports.mainObj = mainObj;
    // Here we return
    // return obj;
    return mainObj(obj);
}
```

EDITED:

I'm calling the procurr(obj) from q1(obj) like so:

```
      // Here we create question question method
     public q1(obj) : any {
       // var topIDs = this.help.obj2Arr(obj);
       var last25 = this.help.last25(obj);
       // Here we return
       return this.procurr(last25);
       // return last25;
     }
```

I'm calling the q1(obj) method from getStaticProps() like so

```
     export async function getStaticProps() {
        const postClass = new Posts();
        // Here we fetch data
        const res = await axios.get('https://hacker- 
        news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json');
        const obj = await res.data;
        // const obj = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res.data));
        // Here we check route request
        const ob = JSON.stringify(postClass.q1(obj));

        // ob = JSON.parse(postClass.q2(obj));
        // ob = JSON.parse(postClass.q3(obj));

        return {
          props: { ob }
        }
    }
```

The API call returns a object containing posts ids from hackernews website

Comment: But why does it kept returning empty object even when I return object with my name not from the fetch

Comment: `return await mainObj(obj);` It's async, so you need to await it

Comment: If I call await outside the async function it request I turn the parent method to async too

Comment: Await will request I turn procurr function to async too and when i do i start having the same problem in procurr

Comment: @JeremyThille [No need for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43985067/1048572), one can just `return` the promise directly. That part of the code works as is.

Comment: Can you show me example on how to do that

Comment: The obvious reason why it doesn't work is that you fill the `robj` array in the loop but then `return ob;` only which is still empty. The less obvious possible reasons are that `ob` might empty from the beginning, so that the `for(item in ob)` loop doesn't run, or that the `word.length` is `0` so the `if` statement doesn't run. Please provide a [mcve] showing the value that you pass to `procurr`

Comment: I returned the ob cause it not empty. I was using it to test if it can just return something. Inside the procurr main function returning the obj which is the ob I passed to the async returns object of ids from an api

Comment: I've also tried returning little object from the async function like {'name':'chinedu'} didn't return anything other than {}

Comment: I've edited and added all the method calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a string of async methods, but at the bottom you forgot to `await` it. If you try to `JSON.stringify` a `Promise` you will get an empty object

```js
const p = new Promise(resolve => resolve({foo:"bar"}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(p)) // Not {foo:"bar"} as you might expect
```

The method you're calling it from is already `async` so just add an `await`

```
const ob = JSON.stringify(await postClass.q1(obj));
```