# Generic promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I currently am managing code that has this function

```
public getData(somei: Somei): Promise<SomeD> {

       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               this.getSomeD(somei).subscribe((someData: SomeD) => {
                   resolve(someData);
               });
        });

    }
```

This works fine. I would like to add a then to perform an action after the code above executes but I dont seem to get it to work.
I tried it like

```
public getData(somei: Somei): Promise<SomeD> {

       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               this.getSomeD(somei).subscribe((someData: SomeD) => {
                   resolve(someData);
               });
        }).then(()=>{callanotherFunction()});

    }
```

but I get the typescript error

```
 Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<SomeD>'.
```

I imagine I have to return the right object type? I should say I am not that familiar with promises.

Comment: *This works fine*: no, it doesn't. If the obervable errors, then your returned promise never resolves, but never errors either. So the caller has no way to know that an error occurred. This is an anti-pattern. Use Observable.toPromise(), or simply return the Observable directly instead of transforming it into a promise. You will have to learn observables to work efficiently with Angular. So now is the best time to start learning them. All you should have is `return this.getSomeD(somei).pipe(tap(() => callanotherFunction()));`

Comment: I assume your `callanotherFunction` is a void function. I suspect you rather only want to return your new Promise.

Comment: You also might want to look up `await` and how it differs from using `then` callbacks.

Comment: In regards that you are not familiar with promises, I have recently written an answer to a somewhat different question, yet you still might find it useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47413446/457268

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
.then(()=>{callanotherFunction()});
```

Is the problem. Since that anonymous function does not return anything (it only invokes `callanotherFunction`), your promise has changed from returning a `SomeD` to returning `void`, which is the error typescript is pointing out to you.

As you say, the solution is to return the right thing. In this case, I think you have two options. Either save the promise to a variable, do your `.then` on that, then return the original. Or you can intercept the result of the original and just forward it in your anonymous function.

Here's an example of both:

```
const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.getSomeD(somei).subscribe((someData: SomeD) => {
        resolve(someData);
    });
});

// Do your code when promise resolves, but return original:
prom.then(() => { callanotherFunction() });
return prom;
```

Or, to just forward the result:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.getSomeD(somei).subscribe((someData: SomeD) => {
        resolve(someData);
    });
}).then(result => { callanotherFunction(); return result; }); // Forward the result
```

Using either of those, the return type will remain as `Promise<SomeD>`.

Answer (score 2):

It's complaining because your second promise (the `then()`) the  is not returning anything, but your signature says it will. If `callanotherFunction` returns something you can return that by removing the braces in the `then` body:

```
then(()=>callanotherFunction());
```

or explicitly return something:

```
.then(()=>{
   return callanotherFunction()
});
```

If `callanotherFunction()` doesn't return anything, then your signature is wrong and should be changed to reflect this:

```
public getData(somei: Somei): Promise<Void> {
```

You can also pass the value from the first promise into then and return it making `callanotherFunction()` just a side-effect:

```
 .then((someData)=>{
   callanotherFunction()
   return someData
});
```

This assumes that `callanotherFunction()` does not perform some async operation that needs to happen first.

Better than all of this is probably to take @jb-nizet's advice in the comments and use the observables directly.

Answer (score -1):

Specify the promise type to be returned

```
return new Promise<SomeD>(/* blablabla */);
```