# handling PromiseRejection in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, jovo-framework

I've just started working with javascript for the first time. From googling I have only been able to find examples of handling promise rejection through functions that have been written by you. My problem is that

```
app.getInput("key");
```

is not written by me. I want to be able to handle the rejected promise in my code. My brain is having trouble "getting javascript" at the moment.

I have this function (in the jovo framework)

```
var content = app.getInput('content');
```

I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined".
I know why I'm getting this error, I just want to be able to handle the situation where there is no content.

It says also "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection"

I just want to be able to write something like

```
var content = "null";

content = testFunc().then(() => {
    console.log('resolved content!');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('error content');
    content = "null";
});

function testFunc(){
    return app.getInput('content');
}
```

Comment: The code you've written should work (maybe except for the `content` variable being rather useless). Please show us the implementation of `app.getInput`, maybe it just does things wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that an non asynchronous method return an error that way. Anyway, now how to handle it

---

**Wrap it with try/catch**

```
let content;

try {
   content = app.getInput('content');

   // All is ok there

   ...
} catch (err) {
  ...
}
```

---

---

@Gabriel Bleu

```js
function a() {
  throw new Error('Error');
}

async function testFunc() {
  try {
    const content = a();
    
    console.log('No error');
    
    return content;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('Error');
  
    return null;
  }
}

testFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to deal with promise is using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
async function testFunc() {
  try {
    const content = await app.getInput('content');
    return content;
  } catch(err) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: We do not `return await`, it's an useless Promise wrapping [Here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise). Moreover getInput do not return a `Promise` object, which is misleading here.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT it's not only returning the promise, but also handling rejection, [see](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7581)

Comment: your link is very interesting indeed. But I did create a snippet (in my answer) and it works without it. I guess there is something special about Promise/setTimeout.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT My answer is based on the fact that `app.getInput` returns a promise.

Comment: ok :) Looking at the [documentation](https://www.jovo.tech/framework/docs/data#getinput) it does not

Answer (score 0):

From your description and from [jovo docs](https://www.jovo.tech/framework/docs/data#getinput), I understand that `getInput()` is a synchronous method. The error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined` is being thrown to the caller (your code). Looks like the framework isn't properly initialized, the `undefined` thing leads me to believe that.

As `Grégory NEUT` answered earlier, you use a `try/catch` block to handle it.

```js
try {
  content = app.getInput('content');

  // All is ok there
} catch (err) {
  // content is unavailable, inspect the error
}
```

The other issue, `"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection"` happens when a promise is rejected and not caught. Perhaps the `try/catch` would solve this, but perhaps not. The fact is that when you call `testFunc()` and it fails, it doesn't returns a rejected promise, so it won't have a method `.then()` as you expected. `Gabriel Bleu` solution would make sure you'll get back a promise in any case.