# Awaiting a .then() statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

If I have this return statement

```
return await foo1().then(() => foo2());
```

and both foo1 and foo2 are async, would the code wait for the resolution of foo2 or only foo1 ?

thanks.

Comment: If a promise returns a promise, it becomes part of the chain, so it will wait for both.  But saying that if your using await, i would drop the then.

Comment: Would it be the same if we had 10 .then ?

Comment: I was just wondering about the behavior of using both in the same line. Thanks

Comment: You can use them both, but I use promises constantly now and very rarely use then.  But it does still come in handy, for example creating a kind of program fork..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` awaits for the entire expression `foo1().then(...)`, regardless of what `...` is. The same applies to a chain of `then`-s (you asked it in a comment).
Also, you do not really need `await` here, you could simply return the `Promise` created by `then` (or a chain of them), see [Difference between `return await promise` and `return promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise) for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`return await somePromise();` is an anti-pattern since 
`await` wraps the result of `somePromise()`, which is itself a Promise, in a newly created Promise.

`return somePromise();` is the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will wait because the `await` operator has lower precedence than the `.` operator.

However, your code fails to take advantage of `await` which provides superior readability.

Prefer

```
await foo1();
const result = await foo2();
return result;
```