# Is there a practical advantage to returning a pending promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

For the most part, I think I understand how async functions work in JavaScript / Node.js, and I am familiar with the syntax of `async`/`await`. But this question is about a very specific case, which I can’t seem to find anywhere, and I think it involves the inner workings of `await`, which is beyond my understanding.

First I’ll start off with a simple example, and then I’ll extend it to real working code. (Note: I’m actually using Typescript, so you’ll see `void` instead of `undefined`, but that’s not important to the problem.)

```
async function subtask() {
    // doSomeStuff();
    return; // returns a `Promise<void>`
}
// async function run() {
//  see options below
// }
function app() {
    run().catch((e) => console.error(e));
}
```

### Option 1

```
async function run() {
    await subtask(); // resolves to `void`
    return; // returns a new `Promise<void>`
}
```

### Option 2

```
async function run() {
    return subtask(); // returns a new Promise, resolving to the `Promise<void>` of `subtask()`
}
```

In the simple example above, I have an async function `run` that calls a smaller async function `subtask`. Both functions must return a `Promise<void>`. I have two options: (1) to await the smaller function and return a new `Promise<void>`, or (2) to return a wrapped promise, given by the smaller function, which will later resolve to `void`.

My lack of understanding is about how this works. In Option 1, is execution is paused before `subtask()` returns? What does that actually mean? Does that mean that the async `subtask` executes synchronously? Does that mean that `app`, which calls `run()`, will also pause execution? What if `app` was async, would that make a difference?

**Is it “better” (more performant) to let the promise bubble up and resolve later, or to resolve it directly within the `run` function?**

The reason this is important is that in my real code I have a bunch of smaller subtasks, which all return void, and then the big function must also return void—it cannot return an array. (Note that the subtasks need not run in any particular order.)

### Option 1

```
async function run() {
    await Promise.all([
        subtask0(),
        subtask1(),
        subtask2(),
    ]);
    return;
}
```

### Option 2

```
async function run() {
    return Promise.all([
        subtask0(),
        subtask1(),
        subtask2(),
    ]).then((_all) => {});
}
```

---

```
function app() {
    // do some stuff
    run(); // if `run` contains `await`, does execution pause here?
           // what if `app` was async?
    // do some more stuff
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use async for option 2, since it is already returning a promise

Comment: @Igor - It's my understanding that a function declared with `async` will return a promise. If I need a function to return a promise, why can't I declare `async` on it? regardless of whether it's `await`ing anything?

Comment: What you are doing there (by adding async and not calling await) is returning a promise wrapped in a promise to the caller.

Comment: On performance, depending on the environment you're building for this is probably polyfilled by typescript into some generator monstrosity. Check the actual resulting code on the typescript playground to see the differences. I think functionally they are all very similar, though async traps exceptions in the returned promise.

Comment: @AlexGuerra the environment is node.js v8+ (i'll put that in the question shortly)

Comment: @Igor - in the link you posted, it says verbatim, **“Async functions always return a promise”**. So when I have an `async` function that explicitly says `return Promise...`, you are right, it's a promise wrapped in a promise. But whenever promises get resolved, if their resolved value *is* a promise, *that* promise also gets resolved. So the question is which option is faster / more performant in terms of the call stack.

Comment: *waits for @Bergi to close this question single-handedly*

Comment: @CodyG. - If you think this question can be improved, you are welcome to suggest edits. If you think it's beyond salvation, you can vote to close. Either way, your comment is unproductive and serves no purpose.

Comment: That was a little harsh of a response... I'm just saying I've seen this question asked and closed before.  `return promise` vs `return await Promise`

Comment: @CodyG. Awesome then! Would love to read any links you have to share.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353087/are-there-performance-concerns-with-return-await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to let the `Promise` bubble up. This avoids the creation of an extra `Promise` object that will also be awaited on (whether this is optimized away behind the scenes in whichever JavaScript engine you're using is up to debate, though).

```
async function run() {
    await subtask();
    return; 
}
```

This creates an extra `Promise` (and subsequently an extra callback in the chain that will be executed).

```
async function run() {
    return subtask(); 
}
```

This isn't actually doing what you think it is. This is also creating an extra `Promise` (since you're using the `async` keyword) and is almost functionally the same as the previous example. By using the `async`  keyword, you're creating and returning a new `Promise` that will resolve/reject to the same value as the `Promise` created from the call to `subtask()`. If you remove the `async` keyword, then this will avoid the creation of the extra unnecessary `Promise` .

Now with your `Promise.all()` examples, I think they're both optimal (assuming you remove the unnecessary `async` keyword from the 2nd one, like noted above). The first would create 2 `Promise` s (the `Promise.all()` one, and the one created from returning from an `async` function), and the 2nd would as well (the `Promise.all()` one, and the one created from calling `then()`). Whichever you'd want to use is basically up to personal choice. Personally, I like the 2nd example since it's not mixing the use of `async` functions and `Promise`s, which I think makes it a little easier to understand.

And for the last part of your question, execution will be paused wherever the `await` keyword exists (so within the `run()` call).

You can also essentially think of the `await` keyword transforming your code from this:

```
// Do some stuff
let result = await run();
// Do some other stuff
```

to this:

```
// Do some stuff
run().then(result => {
    // Do some other stuff
};
```

(the whole point of `await` is to reduce confusion/complexity caused by nesting)

Comment: Good answer but one minor caveat on the last part: `await` and `.then()` are not exactly the same. See [this example on MDN and its following warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Simple_example) demonstrating how you get different results.