# Does an async await Promise resolve require .then() to be called?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

Let's say I have the following async function. The `console.log` will only fire after it has been resolved.

```js
(async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
  console.log('resolved');
})();
```

Is this valid JavaScript? Or should I always use `.then()`? What are the drawbacks or behavioral differences from using `.then()` here?

```js
(async () => {
  return await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
})().then(() => {
  console.log('resolved');
});
```

Off-topic: I also noticed the latest method `return await` can be changed to just `return` without the results changing, but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise) answered that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being able to handle asynchronous operations without always resorting to `then` is the main point of `async/await`. The first example is perfectly valid.

The second one is a bit of an antipattern as it would be functionally identical without the `async/await` for two reasons - marking your function with `async` implicitly makes it return a Promise, but you also explicitly return one - and `await`ing the Promise causes the code to wait until the Promise resolves before returning it, but since you are chaining with `then`, the `then` doesn't run before the Promise resolves anyway.

This would be functionally identical:

```js
(() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
})().then(() => {
  console.log('resolved');
});
```

The main drawback of using "synchronous-like" code like the first example is error handling - if you do 5 `await` operations in a row and any of them reject, your whole `async` function returns a rejected Promise. If you chain `then` operations, you can also insert `catch` handlers to handle specific error cases with more precision.

Comment: Is it really a drawback since you can put try/catch blocks around whatever await-ed operations you have in a row?