# nodejs mongodb - how to return the inserted document using insertOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using `"mongodb": "^3.1.6",`.

I have a method using the drivers [insertOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#insertOne) method (`shops` is my mongoDb database collection):

```
/**
   * Adds a new shop to the shops collection
   * @param {Shop} doc - the new shop to add
   */
  static async addShop(shop) {
    try {
      return await shops.insertOne(shop, {}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          throw e
        }
        return result
      })
      // TODO this should return the new shop
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Something went wrong in addShop : ${e}`)
      throw e
    }
  }
```

Now the method inserts the document into the collection as expected, but does not return the insert result. How do I return the `result` value of the callback function?

For reference - I wrote this unit test that I want to get to pass:

```
test("addShop returns the added shop", async () => {
    const testShop = {
      name: "Test shop for jest unit tests",
    }
    const newShop = await ShopsDAO.addShop(testShop)
    const shoppingCart = global.DBClient.db(process.env.NS)
    const collection = shoppingCart.collection("shops")
    expect(newShop.name).toEqual(testShop.name)
    await collection.remove({ name: testShop.name })
  })
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `insertOne` should return the id of the newly created document: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/. You can subsequently use `findOne` to retrieve the created document: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you not to mix promises and callbacks as it is a bad way to organize your code. [According to docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#insertOne), if you do not pass callback `insertOne` will return `Promise`. So I suggest you to rewrite function smth like that:

```
  static async addShop(shop) {
    try {
      return shops.insertOne(shop)
    } catch (insertError) {
      console.error(`Something went wrong in addShop : ${insertError}`)
      throw insertError
    }
  }
```

This `addShop` will return promise, use await to retrieve data from it:

```
const newShop = await ShopsDAO.addShop(testShop)
```

P.S. [You can also omit await with return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750371/8002036)

Comment: This returns an object with the new inserted document _id. As suggested in the comment above I had to use `findOne` to retrieve and return the new document.