# Is a function that returns a promise always an async function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, angular-promise

I am very confused about which if these three is correct.

```
A(){
Return promise
}
```

```
Async A(){
Return promise
}
```

```
Async A(){
Return await promise //this seems very wrong but still...
}
```

Which of these are correct JavaScript? And if more than one is correct, what is the best practice here, if any?

Answer (score 0):

Async/await can be considered as syntax sugar for Promises. Any function that returns a `Promise` object can be used as an `async` function. The two styles (promise style vs. async/await style) can be mixed without issue.

```
function A() {
  return Promise.resolve('foo');
}

async function B() {
  var aResult = await A();

  return aResult;
}

B().then(console.log);
```

Best practice would be to pick one style and stick with it, for readability. Async/await is the newer style, and has the advantage that it avoids the `.then` [pyramid of doom](https://gist.github.com/fariszacina/a79860e23bb9a6133936).

Note that async/await, or even promises, may not be supported in all runtimes and may require a transpiler (like babel).

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use all of them as all three are valid. But given your examples, only the first makes sense.

Each of your examples returns a Promise. You can either use `a().then(/*...*/)` or `await a()` (only within an `async` function) to get their response when they resolve. Read more about [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) in general.

---

```
function a() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

This is how you should write a function that returns a Promise.

---

```
async function a() {
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

This works as well, but only functions that actually use the `await` keyword need to be annotated with `async`. Functions that just return a Promise without using `await` in their body do not need to be `async`.

---

> ```
> Async A(){
> Return await promise //this seems very wrong but still...
> }
> ```

This is just an unncessary step. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353087/are-there-performance-concerns-with-return-await) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise).