# Simple async await question with function returns

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have a simple yet perplexing issue with async functions.
I wish to simply return the value when its ready from the function.

Here is a sample code:

```js
async function test() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    return 'eeeee';
  }, 5000);
}

test().then(x => {
  console.log(x)
});
```

Comment: Check this please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout

Comment: i should update my comment to be more specific, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combination of async function + await + setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289726/combination-of-async-function-await-settimeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Promises

```
const setTimer = (duration) => {
      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('Done!');
        }, duration);
      });
      return promise;
    };
    
    setTimer(2000).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You will get undefined been logged at once.

It's clear that you are trying to write a `sleep()` async function, but do remember that setTimeout is a sync function calling with a callback function will be executed at a given time, so while you are executing `test()`, the calling will run to end and `return undefined` as you have no return statement in the function body, which will be passed to your `.then()` function.

The right way to do this is to return a Promise that will be resolved after a given time, that will continue the `then` call.

```js
async function sleep(time){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("echo str")
    },time)
  })
}

sleep(5000).then((echo) => console.log(echo))
```

sleep function in short

```js
const sleep = async time => new Promise(resolve=>setTimout(resolve,time))
```

Comment: For those of you who are confused with the `return Promise` and `return await Promise`:[Difference between return await promise and return promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise#:~:text=Most%20of%20the%20time%2C%20there,between%20return%20and%20return%20await%20.&text=The%20second%20version%20of%20the,caller%20gets%20the%20rejection%20instead.)

Answer (score 0):

An async function has to return a promise. So to fix this, you can wrap your `setTimeout` function in a new promise like so:

```
async function test(){
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function(){
          resolve('eeeee');
      },5000);
  })
}

test().then(x => {
  console.log(x)
});
```

You can learn more about async/await on the MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Hope this helps!