# javascript await in the caller and in the callee

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a service class called: `Test`

That `Test` Class has a function called: `getMe()`

In that `getMe` function, I have 3 await statements, 2nd needs the answer from the first one, third one needs an answer from the second one. An example:

```js
class Test {
   async getMe() {
      const res1 = await promise1;
      const res2 = await promise2(res1);
      const res3 = await promise3(res2);
      return res3;
   }
}
```

Now, somewhere in my code, i call this function.

```
const a = new Test();
try{
  const res = await a.getMe();
}catch(err){
  console.log("error", err);
}
```

Now, because of the fact that in `getMe` function, I already await promises, It's not optimized since there's a middle promise created. Read this: [Difference between `return await promise` and `return promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise)

So, I am wondering, If in the `getMe` function, I shouldn't write `await` for optimizations and return promise directly, how could my code be written ? I don't want in my outside code to call `await` promise1, promise2, promise3 because then I'd not have a single function which takes care of the final bits and my code would be scattered.

What do you think and could be your advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the promises inside `getMe()` are dependent on each other (e.g. `promise2` requires the resolved value of `promise1` as an input-parameter), you cannot really optimize something here (apart from directly returning the last promise).

If they weren't dependent on other you could certainly use `Promise.all()` in order to process them non-sequentially, return its promise and just await this promise in the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you could do to optimize it, would be to return the result of `promise3` directly.

```
class Test {
   async getMe() {
      const res1 = await promise1;
      const res2 = await promise2(res1);
      return promise3(res2);
   }
}
```

Other than that, I dont see any way, as the three functions are dependent on one another.