# Detect missing await in JavaScript methods in VSCode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I'm searching for some eslint option, or some other way to detect missing the 'await' keyword before calling async methods inside a class. Consider the following code:

```
const externalService = require('./external.service');

class TestClass {

constructor() { }

async method1() {
    if (!await externalService.someMethod()) {
        await this.method2();
    }
}

async method2() {
    await externalService.someOtherMethod();
}

module.exports = TestClass;
```

There will be no warning if I will convert method1 to:

```
async method1() {
    if (!await externalService.someMethod()) {
        this.method2();
    }
}
```

I tried to do on the '.eslintrc' file:

```
"require-await": 1,
"no-return-await": 1,
```

But with no luck. Anyone have an idea if it is even possible?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Calling an `async` function without `await` is actually totally valid, you just get a `Promise` in return so I doubt linters allow this kind of rule (which is very restrictive)

Comment: @GuerricP I edited the code, method2 will call external method (let's say you don't know what's the code in there, it's a third party code).

Comment: You might be able to use rule [no-floating-promises](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md). It behaves slightly different, but I think it will catch this case.

Comment: @Automatico, Thanks, will check it.

Comment: This is a very good question and in my view a very important thing to check for.  Missing awaits can cause really nasty asynchronous/race condition bugs.  In my view, despite what others here have said, it is rarely intended to not await an async and in those cases where it is the author should be explicitly disabling a lint rule and making clear why they're doing it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) has a rule for this: [`no-floating-promises`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md)

> This rule forbids usage of Promise-like values in statements without handling their errors appropriately ... Valid ways of handling a Promise-valued statement include `await`ing, returning, and either calling `.then()` with two arguments or `.catch()` with one argument.

As you probably figured out from the name, typescript-eslint is designed to add TypeScript support to eslint, but you can use it with JavaScript as well. I guess it's your call to decide whether it's overkill for this one rule, but here are the steps:

1. Generate a `tsconfig.json` file

   ```
   npx tsc --init
   ```
2. Install dependencies

   ```
   npm install --save-dev eslint @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser
   ```
3. Modify your `.eslintrc` file

   Based on my testing it looks like you'll need these entries at a minimum:

   ```json
   {
     "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
     "parserOptions": { "project": "./tsconfig.json" },
     "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
     "rules": {
       "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": ["error"]
     }
   }
   ```

If there are places where you want to call an async function without using `await`, you can either:

- Use the `void` operator as mentioned in the [documentation for the rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises/), e.g.

  ```
  void someAsyncFunction();
  ```
- Or just change `error` to `warn` in the `.eslintrc` configuration above

The documentation for setting up typescript-eslint is here for more info: https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/linting

Next time you run eslint you should see the rule applied:

```bash
$ npm run lint
...
./services/jobService.js
  11:5  warning  Promises must be awaited, end with a call to .catch, end with a call to .then with a rejection handler or be explicitly marked as ignored with the `void` operator  @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises
```

Since you mentioned VS Code specifically, this also integrates great with the [ESLint plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint):

[image: vscode showing no-floating-promises rule]

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: I found to use void to pass the check, I had to add an option to the ESLint rule `"@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": ["error", { "ignoreVoid": true }],`

Comment: @PulpDood It's odd you had to set `ignoreVoid` to `true` since that's already the default as per [the documentation](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises/#options)

Answer (score 3):

`require-await` says "Don't make a function `async` unless you use `await` inside it".

This is because `async` has two effects:

- It forces the function to return a promise
- It lets you use `await` inside it

The former is rarely useful which mean if you aren't using `await` inside the function you need to question why you marked it as `async`.

---

`no-return-await` stops you from doing:

```
return await something
```

Because `await` unwraps a value from a promise, but returning a value from an `async` function wraps it in a promise.

Since *just* returning a promise causes that promise to be adopted, combining `return` with `await` is just bloat.

---

So neither of those do what you want.

Which brings us to your actual desire.

**Such a feature does not (as far as I know) exist in ESLint, and I don't think it would be useful to have one.**

There are lots of use cases where you don't want to await something returned by an `async` function.

e.g.

```
const array_of_promises = array_of_values.map( value => do_something_async(value) );
const array_of_resolved_values = await Promise.all(array_of_promises);
```

The above is a common use-case where you want to run a bunch of async functions in parallel and then wait for them all to resolve.

Another example is the case that `no-return-await` is designed to detect!

Cases like these are common enough that most people wouldn't want their toolchain calling them out for doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I wish that Eslint would let me have the option to control it, if I want a warning or not in cases like this.

Comment: https://dev.to/spukas/how-to-write-your-first-eslint-plugin-145

Comment: Quentin, Thanks, Good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an ESLint plugin for this that you can use as an alternative to the typescript-eslint route:

https://github.com/SebastienGllmt/eslint-plugin-no-floating-promise

Comment: It does not work across file boundaries (if import a function from a different file, you don't have any information)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the combination of eslint rules for a better version of checking `await`:

[No-floating-promises](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises/)

[return-await](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/return-await.md) with try-catch option to able catch the Promise rejection ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise))