# Second layer nested promise

Tags: typescript, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

I have an advanced Mongo query.

Where I try to count distinct values for a number of fields.

First I have to iterate over three values, which are entries n my Mongoose schema, and then I have to count each distinct value for each of the respective field, and return them as a string.

```js
const mappedStuff = this.featureFields.map(async field => {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const distinctValues = await this.gameModel.distinct(field);
        return distinctValues.map(async entry => {
          console.log(
            `${field}, ${entry},  ${await this.gameModel.count({
              [field]: entry,
            })}`,
          ); //Logs out correct value 
          resolve(
            `${field}, ${entry},  ${await this.gameModel.count({
              [field]: entry,
            })}` as string, //resolves instantly and does not return the correct value
          );
        });
      });
    });
    console.log(Promise.all(mappedStuff));
    return Promise.all(mappedStuff);
```

The console.log works fine, and I just want to return that value, I have tried pushing it to a list outside, but does not work, because I have an `await` inside of the string.

Therefore I tried wrapping the entire thing in a promise, but this does not solve the issue either. Does anybody have a solution

Comment: What is your desired output? `Promise.all()` doesn't wait for all promises deeply without using `Promise.all` again in the second layer of promises. Also, creating a new promise in an async function is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did the right thing wrapping the outer array with *Promise.all()*, but you forgot to do the same thing with the inner array, where you have `distinctValues.map(//...`.  Additionally, the Promise directly inside the outer map seems superfluous.

```
const mappedStuff = this.featureFieldsMap.map(async (field) => {
  const distinctValues = await this.gameModel.distinct(field);
  return await Promise.all(distinctValues.map(async (entry) => {
    // make life easier by not interpolating the asynchronous result.
    const count = await this.gameModel.count({ [field]: entry });
    return `${field}, ${entry}, ${count}`;
  }));
});
return Promise.all(mappedStuff);
```

Comment: +1, though you can always return a Promise from within an `async` function (and an `async` function is going to return a Promise anyway) so you can avoid `return await` in favor of `return`. The Promise implementation does the unwrapping.

Comment: It was anti-pattern to return a Promise in a async context, but I got really frustrated with this! I should have though of mapping the `distinctValues` and wrapping the result in `Promise.all()` inside of the map function. Thank you @Daniel Gimenez

Comment: @JeffBowman, so this makes the `await` before the return redundant. Similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise

Comment: @Ating Correct. The outer map is an async lambda, and there's no try/catch, so `return await Promise.all(...)` works but is no better than `return Promise.all(...)`. I agree it's an antipattern to _create an explicit Promise_ in an async context, so I agree with Daniel in removing it, but directly returning a Promise from a helper like `Promise.all` is perfectly reasonable.