# Return type for asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, flowtype

I have this code that is a simple implementation of async/await while doing ajax call

```
export const getExternalResource = async (): Promise|String|null => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>{
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = response.json();

        if(json) {
            resolve(json);
        } else {
            resolve(null)
        }
    });
};

/**
 * @var resource will be null|string
 */
const resource = await getExternalResource();
```

My question is what is the correct return type for the `getExternalResource()` function?

In code it returns a promise, however when calling the function with `await` keyword, it returns a basic data type (string|null).

Comment: `Promise<String | null>`? Flow still has generics AFAIK and they should be used like that.

Comment: Also: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743) + [Is it an anti-pattern to use async/await inside of a new Promise() constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229)

Comment: The explicit `new Promise` is pointless, `fetch` already returns promises, and you’re even using `async`/`await` on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a `fetch` inside a `Promise` since `fetch` returns a promise. Also return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise type. So changed the return type here to `Promise<any>`. You can replace `any` with the matching type

```
export const getExternalResource = async(url: string): Promise<any> => {
  return await fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
};
const resource = getExternalResource('url').then(d=>d);
```

Comment: `return await` [is quite redundant here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise). Since there is no `try/catch` it's useless. `return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());` is the same but simpler. As for `getExternalResource('url').then(d=>d);` - [the `.then(d=>d)` is useless and should be omitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41089122/is-thenfunctiona-return-a-a-no-op-for-promises). No real reason to drop the `await`, either - OP's code had it and it's what they wanted.