# async await with no return statement?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await, return

So... I've searched for quite a while and never found a definitive answer... Is there anything wrong or less than ideal with an async function with no return statement?

For instance, this doesn't compile:

```
// abstract a function to update a database that could work across multiple databases
public async updateGenericDatabase(v: string): Promise<void>
{
    // the database specific client returns a non-void value so this won't compile:
    // (and return await used to be taboo but now it's preferred, lol...)
    return await updateSpecificDAandReturnNonVoid(v); // won't compile...
}
```

So instead,

```
public async updateGenericDatabase(v: string): Promise<void>
{
    await updateSpecificDAandReturnNonVoid(v); // does compile, but...
}
```

But this just feels WRONG, since it doesn't explicity return a promise... and since I'm awaiting on behalf of... whom? yet I can't actually think of anything wrong with it...

Anyone care to say "yeah, this is totally legit" or "NO NO NO this is code stink you should never ever do this"?

Thanks in advance: The Internet

Comment: When you call the database, the database manage your call stack to be process, no need async await if you don't receive anything. Perhaps, returns non void value, so treat without saying "void" at return type and set "any" at this case needs to establish the return with async await only if doing an external request (That's my point of view)

Comment: If someone wants to provide a better example of where this pattern is appropriate I will gladly mark it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

All `async` functions return a promise. If you return a non-promise value from an `async` function, it is implicitly wrapped in the promise returned by the `async` function.

If you return a promise from an `async` function, then you have two promises: `async` function promise (let's call it p1) and the promise returned inside the `async` function body (let's call it p2).

In this case, p1 promise will wait for p2 promise to settle (fulfil / reject). This is referred to as p1 promise *resolving* to p2 promise. This results in p1 promise waiting for p2 promise to settle and after p2 settles, p1 will meet the same fate as p2, i.e., p1 will fulfil if p2 fulfils. Similarly, p1 will get rejected if p2 is rejected.

---

Coming to your code, if you want to wait for the promise returned by `updateSpecificDAandReturnNonVoid` to settle and get its fulfilment value, then you need to add the `return` statement inside the `async` function.

Not adding the `return` statement will result in `async` function promise to fulfil with the value of `undefined` because that is what implicitly gets returned from a function in JavaScript if it doesn't explicitly return any value. Code will still wait for the promise returned by `updateSpecificDAandReturnNonVoid` to settle but the promise fulfilment value won't be used.

> Anyone care to say "yeah, this is totally legit" or "NO NO NO this is code stink you should never ever do this"?

It depends on the requirement. Do you need to return the promise fulfilment value? if yes, return the promise from the `async` function. If no, then you can skip returning the promise and just `await` the promise inside the `async` function.

---

**Note:**

You can replace

```
return await updateSpecificDAandReturnNonVoid(v);
```

with

```
return updateSpecificDAandReturnNonVoid(v);
```

This works because the promise returned by `updateSpecificDAandReturnNonVoid` is returned inside the `async` function and as explained above, the `async` function promise will automatically wait for the returned inner promise to settle before settling itself. The `await` keyword in such cases is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks. As for the requirement, caller won't care about the specific fulfillment value, so Promise<void>. Caller will care about catching any exceptions propagating from updateSpecificDAandReturnNonVoid, and therefore the ability to await on updateSpecificDAandReturnNonVoid by awaiting on updateGenericDatabase. Given your answer, it sounds to me like the code without a return statement is perfectly fine in this regard (those regards?), and that tests out, yeah. Again, thanks.

Comment: Per the last bit, the latest seems to be to prefer return await SomePromise() over return SomePromise b/c return await is both faster and has a cleaner stack trace: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/17345

Comment: I doubt that the performance difference (if at all) will hardly be noticeable. See: [Difference between `return await promise` and `return promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708550/difference-between-return-await-promise-and-return-promise)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, this is fine.

Long answer is I was mixing this up with the "oops" case below, which, in hindsight, I think is somewhat understandable.

async and await serve different purposes. All async functions return promises, and it is preferable to mark all functions that return promises as async, but you can have an async function without an await in it.

```
async function consolidateErrors(): Promise<string>
{
    // Since this function returns a promise, mark it async.

    // async makes the compiler (or interpreter) wrap this exception in a
    // failed Promise so that the caller only has to deal with a promise
    // as a return value. This makes things much simpler for the caller.
    if (someUnwantedCondition)
    {
        throw new Error("async simplifies error handling");
    }

    // there is no await in this function, and that's fine.
    return callSomeFunctionThatReturnsAPromise();
}
```

Since all async functions return promises, at some point I mistakenly thought you could do something like this:

```
async function oops(): Promise<void>
{
    // No return or await here. This might not be what you want.

    // This disconnects the caller of oops from callAsyncFunction.
    // Any errors thrown by callAsyncFunction will not propagate to
    // a caller of oops, and a caller of oops cannot await on the
    // promise returned by callAsyncFunction, since oops neither
    // awaits nor returns that promise.
    callAsyncFunction();

    // This function will return a promise, but this promise will have
    // nothing to do with the promise returned from callAsyncFunction.
}
```

There are cases where it's okay to let go of a promise:

```
function handleSomeButtonClick(): void
{
    // The caller of handleSomeButtonClick (the DOM) doesn't care
    // about what happens in callAsyncFunction.
    // callAsyncFunction will either complete, or an error will be
    // logged within that function.
    callAsyncFunction();
}
```

But in cases where you do have responsibility to the caller, where you don't want the inner promise to get lost, using await without a return statement is fine, it ensures errors will propagate to the caller:

```
async function thisIsFine(): Promise<void>
{
    await callAsyncFunction();
}

async function doSomethingAndHandleExceptions(): Promise<void>
{
    try {
        // thisIsFine(); // nope! exceptions won't be caught here.
        await thisIsFine();
    }
    catch (err: unknown) {
        // handle the error...
    }
}

function handleClick(): void
{
    doSomethingAndHandleExceptions();
}
```

When you await, it's kind of like adding a then clause and a catch clause by other means, where async hooks it all together for you.

To round things out you might want to understand [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750371/431425) as well.

Hope this helps someone other than me!